# Matching list of eigenvalues and eigenvectors and removing negative values

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, eigenvalues

I Have a matrix M (14x14) dimension in terms of variable k. Due to the complexity I wish to diagonalize M numerically as I can't symbolically.

```
Chop[Table[Eigensystem[M],{k,0,2*Pi,0.01}]]
```

This gives me a multidimensional aray of eigenvalues and eigenvectors. My goal is to extract the eigenvectors corresponding to positive eigenvalues as the eigenvalues of M are 7 positive and 7 negative and the 7 positive correspond to energy values for each k, where I want a list of eigenvalues and eigenvectors for each k. I have been trying to order the eigenvalues and eigenvectors with little success.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
{λ, U} = Eigensystem[A];
pos = Position[λ, _?Positive];
Extract[λ, pos]
Extract[U, pos]
```

where `A` is just any numerical matrix (e.g. `A = M /.k-> <<your parameter here>>`).

Comment: Thank you for responding! I shouldn't been clearer in my question though that I can't symbolically evaluate Eigensystem[M]

Comment: The matrix M is in terms of variable k and cannot be solved (diagonalized) as a function of k instead numerical values of k must be used and I want an order list iterated over k of eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Comment: Well, then just put the code I posted into your `Table`. Really: I can cook a meal for you, but you have to eat it yourself.

Comment: Indeed, However this was the crux of my question!